# How do I migrate an existing tomcat application to AWS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, migration

I am trying to migrate a tomcat application to AWS. Does it still mean I will be using tomcat on a AWS instance? What will be some of the challenges doing so?

Comment: You don't need to make very many changes.  Perhaps a few config changes in `server.xml`.  Other than this, it should directly port over to AWS, assuming the Tomcat and Java versions are the same in both places.

Comment: Depends what you want to do. A serverless architecture like lambda will require some code changes. If youre just hosting on an EC2 instance it's going to be identical, provided that your AMI has the same system software installed. You may need to do some updates regarding durable vs non-durable storage options for disk (updating directory definitions for stored files)